# Internet Explorer 11 и global.ymaps.modules

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, гис

Наблюдаются проблемы с работой гос.порталов с Internet explorer 11, например ГИС ЖКХ.
Некорретно отображается даже главная страница портала. В консоле IE11 ругается на global.ymaps.modules (Не удалось получить свойство "modules" ссылки, значение которой не определено или является NULL): var ym={project:{preload:["package.system"],namespace:"ymaps",jsonpPrefix:"",loadLimit:500},ns:{},env:{},envCallbacks:[]};**ym.modules=global.ymaps.modules**;

"angular" не определено
angular.module('pafo-analytics-web-package.routes', [])

"jQuery" не определено
jQuery.holdReady( true );

Comment: Internet Explorer это старый и проблемный браузер, поэтому вполне нормальны ситуации когда в нем что-то работает некорректно / не работает вовсе. Это ответственность Microsoft, в первую очередь: включая этот браузер в винду на протяжении многих лет, они не выпускали его обновлений для соответствия актуальным стандартам. По сути, IE это "гость из далекого прошлого", полностью оторванный от сегодняшней реальности веба. Раньше веб-разработчики пытались поддерживать IE, но теперь все чаще забивают на него (имхо, такая тенденция вебу только на пользу).

Comment: К сожалению, множество программ завязано на движок IE. Все понимают, что это унылое г*вно, но поделать пока нельзя. Переписывать программу под EDGE или Хромиум, очень долго и затратно.

Comment: Помимо переписывания тех самых программ, остается только один вариант: клевать мозг техподдержке гос.порталов, чтобы они клевали мозг своим коллегам-разработчикам, чтобы те добавили в сборку вебприложений все необходимые полифиллы для IE :) То есть, вообще это может быть решаемо на стороне сервиса, но увы, не во всех случаях... потому что не все из отсутствующих в IE возможностей можно компенсировать полифиллом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Работа в государственной информационной системе жилищно-коммунального хозяйства поддерживается в текущих версиях следующих браузеров:

•   Google Chrome;
•   Mozilla Firefox;
•   Apple Safari.

В настоящее время поддержка Windows XP прекращена и установка текущей версии указанных выше браузеров невозможна.

На текущий момент государственным заказчиком, ответственным за координацию работ по созданию, эксплуатации и модернизации системы, является Минстрой России (извлечение из части 1 статьи 7 Федерального закона от 21.07.2014 № 209-ФЗ "О государственной информационной системе жилищно-коммунального хозяйства" в редакции федерального закона от 27.12.2019 № 523-ФЗ "О внесении изменений в статьи 7 и 9 Федерального закона "О государственной информационной системе жилищно-коммунального хозяйства"). С правилами рассмотрения электронных обращений Вы можете ознакомиться на официальном сайте Минстроя России по адресу: http://www.minstroyrf.ru/contact/

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, множество программ завязано на движок IE. Все понимают, что это унылое программное обеспечение, но ничего поделать пока нельзя. Переписывать программу под EDGE или Хромиум, очень долго и затратно.